# Cypher accessing space separated relationship property neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a few million nodes large data set imported with https://github.com/jexp/batch-import .

Unfortunately, the script made relationship property names space separated as in "Some Property".

How do I ask for this property in Cypher?

As expected

```
r.Some Property
```

does not work, which is only fair.

I also tried:

```
r["Some Property"]
```

Is there a syntax for such naming?

Should I just redo the import with camel case property names or underscore separated ones?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return properties with spaces in the names by using backticks, `, to enclose the property name. Something like this should work in Cypher:

```
START r=rel(0) RETURN r.`Some Property`;
```

This goes for node properties as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `MATCH (r) WHERE r.type=~'Some Property.*' RETURN r;`

I hope this will get you exact relation-type.

OR

`MATCH (n)-[r]->() WHERE type(r)=~'S.*'` It will give you all relationship started with `S`.